# Side of a triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

In the figure, $AB=10\sqrt2$, $AC=11\sqrt2$ and $BC=12\sqrt2$.$DE$ and $BC$ are parallel and divides the triangle into two parts with equal area. What is the length of the
line DE?

Comment: What can you say about triangles $ADE$ and $ABC$? (Or what did you try to solve this yourself?)

Comment: Hint: The ratio of areas of two similar triangles is equal to the ratio of squares of their sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADE and ABC are similar.And then using the fact that ratio of areas of two similar triangles is equal to the ratio of squares of their sides we get (DE/BC)^2 =1/2, which gives you DE=12.

Answer (score -1):

A parallel line divides area as the square of corresponding sides of the similar triangles. I.e.,

$$ \dfrac {Area_{ADE}} {Area_{ABC} } = (DE/BC)^2  =\frac12 $$

So,

$$ DE = BC /\sqrt2 =12. $$

Comment: Can the negative voter/s frankly state why the negative voting ?

Comment: I guess the downvoter was in a bad day...